# AWS CDK: How to merge a Legacy swagger and a CDK-defined resource in one API?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

Here's what I did:

```js
const apiHelper = new apigateway.SpecRestApi(this, 'AppTestCdkHelper', {
  apiDefinition: apigateway.ApiDefinition.fromAsset(__dirname + '/apigateway-App.json'),
});

const api = new apigateway.RestApi(this, 'AppTestCdkGood', {
  cloneFrom: apiHelper,
});

const integration = new apigateway.HttpIntegration('http://example.com/abc/xyz', { ... });
api.root.addResource('abc').addMethod('get', integration);
```

When deployed, I got two APIs:

1. `AppTestCdkHelper` that contains the legacy schema only.
2. `AppTestCdkGood` that contains all what I want: the legacy schema and the new resource.

**The Question:** How to avoid the `AppTestCdkHelper` creation in the cloud?

I use it in CDK because `RestApi()` cannot accept the `ApiDefinition`.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

```js
const api = new apigateway.RestApi(this, 'AppTestCdkGood');

// A hack, based on apigateway.SpecRestApi constructor
const apiDefConfig = apigateway.ApiDefinition.fromAsset(__dirname + '/apigateway-Salesforce.json').bind(api);
(api.node.defaultChild as apigateway.CfnRestApi).bodyS3Location = apiDefConfig.s3Location;

const integration = new apigateway.HttpIntegration('http://example.com/abc/xyz', { ... });
api.root.addResource('abc').addMethod('get', integration);
```

All the operations in the hack are valid and based on API, except the type cast.

The type cast `(api.node.defaultChild as apigateway.CfnRestApi)` is based on implementation and might break in the future updates.

Comment: where is the `api2` variable reference coming from or this supposed to be simply `api`?

Comment: @BigRich Thanks, it was a mistype. I cleaned up the sources after my experiments and missed some parts.